# Cropping Image using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a program where the user is able to crop a selected area via mouse or textbox. Right now I'm only able to crop via textbox. Since I'm implementing MVVM I don't know how to implement the crop functionality in my ViewModel. I'm already able to draw rectangles over the image, I implemented this in the code behind.
My Problem now is how can I implement the crop functionality in the ViewModel with the values I get from my view code behind?

My Xaml (View)

```
<Window x:Class="PROSE.MinimizeImage.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PROSE"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:wi="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="575" Width="450">
<StackPanel Margin="10">
    <Grid x:Name="GridLoadedImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="400" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}"/>
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <Canvas Name ="cnvImage">
            <Image x:Name="_image" Margin="10" Source="{Binding CurrentImage.ImagePath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Fill" MaxHeight="300"
               MouseDown="_image_MouseDown" MouseMove="_image_MouseMove" MouseUp="_image_MouseUp"/>
        </Canvas>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentImage}" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" MaxHeight="40"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
    <WrapPanel>
        <Label Content="X Field" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentImage.CropXPosition, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="40" />
        <Label Content="Y Field" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentImage.CropYPosition, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="40" />
        <Label Content="Height Field" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentImage.CropHeight, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="40" />
        <Label Content="Width Field" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentImage.CropWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="40" />
    </WrapPanel>
    <WrapPanel>
        <Label Content="Width cm" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentImage.ResizeWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="40" />
        <Label Content="Height cm" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentImage.ResizeHeight, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="40" />
    </WrapPanel>
    <WrapPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding ResizeCommand}">Resize</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" Content="Open"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding CropCommand}">Crop</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Content="Save"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

The Code behind (View)

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Point startPoint;
    private Rectangle rectSelectArea;
    private bool isDragging = false;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }

    private void _image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        startPoint = e.GetPosition(cnvImage);

        if (rectSelectArea != null)
            cnvImage.Children.Remove(rectSelectArea);

        rectSelectArea = new Rectangle
        {
            Stroke = Brushes.LightBlue,
            StrokeThickness = 2
        };

        Canvas.SetLeft(rectSelectArea, startPoint.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(rectSelectArea, startPoint.X);
        cnvImage.Children.Add(rectSelectArea);
    }

    private void _image_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released || rectSelectArea == null)
            return;

        var pos = e.GetPosition(cnvImage);

        //set the position of rectangle
        var x = Math.Min(pos.X, startPoint.X);
        var y = Math.Min(pos.Y, startPoint.Y);

        //set the dimension of rectangle
        var w = Math.Max(pos.X, startPoint.X) - x;
        var h = Math.Max(pos.Y, startPoint.Y) - y;

        rectSelectArea.Width = w;
        rectSelectArea.Height = h;

        Canvas.SetLeft(rectSelectArea, x);
        Canvas.SetTop(rectSelectArea, y);
    }

    private void _image_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
         // rectSelectArea = null;
    }
}
```

I came across various post threads but none of them could really help me.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs` - something is wrong here. And as for the question, you can call method of view model from the view: `((MainViewModel)this.DataContext).SomeMethod(...);`, passing values as parameters.

Comment: MVVM != no codebehind.  Cropping an image using a mouse is *specifically a UI concern*.  Do not try to force it into the view model due to fealty to an incorrect understanding of a pattern.

Comment: @Sinatr Oh yeah true, I was trying something out but it didn't work. I edited it. And so you mean I can implement a method in the view model and call it from the view? Is it also possible to use the values I get in from the view in the view model?

Comment: @Will so you mean i could implement the functionality of the cropping in the view?

Comment: I would argue that while the mouse selection logic belongs in the view, the actual cropping logic *does* belong in the view-model (or some other business layer).  In your case, the cropping isn't directly related to the presentation of the image, it is an actual business function.

Comment: Absolutely. There's no reason not to, and you have full access to all the information you need.

Comment: @BradleyUffner That's what I thought too and that's why I didn't how to continue.

Comment: @Will I also understand your view and that way it is definitely easier to do it

Comment: I would have the mouse selection logic in the view; have it provide a `Rectangle` of the selected region that can be read by the view-model.  Have the actual cropping action fire based off of an `ICommand` implementtion, that takes the image, the the selected bounds, and then performs the cropping somewhere outside the view.  You could use something like MVVMLight's `Messenger` class to communicate between view and view-model if needed.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yeah I already implemented the mouse selection in the view. But thanks, I'll take a look at it and see how it goes. I never worked with MVVM Light, is the messenger something easy to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a Blend behavior that implements your cropping actions and give the behavior a bindable ICommand property that you invoke on MouseUp (and possibly some other conditions). You could then bind an ICommand property (from your viewmodel) to this property so that your viewmodel will be passed the desired values when the cropping is completed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195718(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is a "rough" sample that crops an image and saves the cropped image:

**ViewModel**

```
public class ShellViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public string Title => "Sample";

    public ICommand SelectionCommand => new DelegateCommand<byte[]>(buffer =>
    {
        var path = @"C:\temp\output.bmp";

        File.WriteAllBytes(path, buffer);

        Process.Start(path);
    });
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="Poc.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Poc.ViewModels"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Poc.Views.Interactivity.Behaviors"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="{Binding Title}" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:ShellViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="Image" Source="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" Stretch="Fill" />
    <Canvas Background="Transparent">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:CroppingBehavior x:Name="CroppingBehavior" Stroke="White" Thickness="2" SelectionCommand="{Binding SelectionCommand}" TargetElement="{Binding ElementName=Image}" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Canvas>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10">
        <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=CroppingBehavior, Path=SaveCommand}"  Padding="10">Save</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=CroppingBehavior, Path=ClearCommand}" Margin="4, 0,0,0" Padding="10">Clear</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Behavior**

```
public class CroppingBehavior : Behavior<Canvas>
{
    #region Fields

    public DependencyProperty SelectionCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SelectionCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(CroppingBehavior));

    public DependencyProperty StrokeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Stroke), typeof(Brush), typeof(CroppingBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Fuchsia));
    public DependencyProperty ThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Thickness), typeof(double), typeof(CroppingBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(2d));

    public DependencyProperty StrokeDashCapProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(StrokeDashCap), typeof(PenLineCap), typeof(CroppingBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(PenLineCap.Round));
    public DependencyProperty StrokeEndLineCapProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(StrokeEndLineCap), typeof(PenLineCap), typeof(CroppingBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(PenLineCap.Round));
    public DependencyProperty StrokeStartLineCapProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(StrokeStartLineCap), typeof(PenLineCap), typeof(CroppingBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(PenLineCap.Round));

    public DependencyProperty TargetElementProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TargetElement), typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(CroppingBehavior));

    private Point _startPoint;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public ICommand SelectionCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(SelectionCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectionCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public Brush Stroke
    {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(StrokeProperty);
        set => SetValue(StrokeProperty, value);
    }

    public double Thickness
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ThicknessProperty);
        set => SetValue(ThicknessProperty, value);
    }

    public PenLineCap StrokeDashCap
    {
        get => (PenLineCap)GetValue(StrokeDashCapProperty);
        set => SetValue(StrokeDashCapProperty, value);
    }

    public PenLineCap StrokeEndLineCap
    {
        get => (PenLineCap)GetValue(StrokeEndLineCapProperty);
        set => SetValue(StrokeEndLineCapProperty, value);
    }

    public PenLineCap StrokeStartLineCap
    {
        get => (PenLineCap)GetValue(StrokeStartLineCapProperty);
        set => SetValue(StrokeStartLineCapProperty, value);
    }

    public ICommand ClearCommand => new DelegateCommand(() => AssociatedObject.Children.Clear());

    public ICommand SaveCommand => new DelegateCommand(OnSave);

    public FrameworkElement TargetElement
    {
        get => (FrameworkElement)GetValue(TargetElementProperty);
        set => SetValue(TargetElementProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.MouseDown += OnMouseDown;
        AssociatedObject.MouseMove += OnMouseMove;
        AssociatedObject.MouseUp += OnMouseUp;
    }

    private void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            var pos = e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);

            //set the position of rectangle
            var x = Math.Min(pos.X, _startPoint.X);
            var y = Math.Min(pos.Y, _startPoint.Y);

            //set the dimension of rectangle
            var w = Math.Max(pos.X, _startPoint.X) - x;
            var h = Math.Max(pos.Y, _startPoint.Y) - y;

            var rectangle = new Rectangle
            {
                Stroke = Stroke,
                StrokeThickness = Thickness,
                StrokeDashCap = StrokeDashCap,
                StrokeEndLineCap = StrokeEndLineCap,
                StrokeStartLineCap = StrokeStartLineCap,
                StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round,
                Width = w,
                Height = h
            };
            AssociatedObject.Children.Clear();
            AssociatedObject.Children.Add(rectangle);

            Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, x);
            Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, y);
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _startPoint = e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        AssociatedObject.MouseDown -= OnMouseDown;
        AssociatedObject.MouseUp -= OnMouseMove;
        AssociatedObject.MouseUp -= OnMouseUp;
    }

    private void OnSave()
    {
        if (TargetElement != null)
        {
            var rectangle = AssociatedObject.Children.OfType<Rectangle>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (rectangle != null)
            {
                var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)TargetElement.ActualWidth, (int)TargetElement.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

                bmp.Render(TargetElement);

                var cropped = new CroppedBitmap(bmp, new Int32Rect((int)_startPoint.X, (int)_startPoint.Y, (int)rectangle.Width, (int)rectangle.Height));

                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();

                    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(cropped));
                    encoder.QualityLevel = 100;
                    encoder.Save(stream);

                    SelectionCommand?.Execute(stream.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This application uses the Expression.Blend.Sdk.WPF and Prism.Core NuGet packages.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Is there an example anywhere for me to better understand? It's quite hard to follow for me right now since I'm new to WPF and MVVM

Comment: Thanks a lot! For some reasons I didn't get any notifications that you edited your reply. So sorry for the late reply. But really appreciate your effort!